# Why cannot I set UIScreen.main.brightness?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I just started making a new app. The code `UIScreen.main.brightness = 1.0` does not work anywhere. I tried it in `viewDidLoad`, tried it in `viewWillAppear`. I commented out everything else and making this the only line of code that is run, but it is not working. I cannot change brightness. I am trying it on a real device which is my iPhone X - iOS 13.4.1. What could be the reason?

Edit:Also tried with a new Xcode project. Still does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I notice that in iOS 13, calls to UIScreen.main.brightness from viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear don't have any effect.  Adding it to viewDidAppear works fine.

It also worked fine putting in button action.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var brightness: CGFloat = 1.0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let button = UIButton(type: .infoDark)

        // This call is ignored
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.3)
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 40.0, y: 100.0, width: button.frame.width, height: button.frame.height)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toggle), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        // This call is also ignored
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.8)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        // This call sets the brightness
        UIScreen.main.brightness = 0.5
    }

    @objc func toggle() {
        brightness = brightness - 0.2
        print("brightness is \(brightness)")
        if brightness < 0 { brightness = 1.0 }
        // This call changes the brightness
        UIScreen.main.brightness = brightness
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

I found something interesting!
If you set brightness from code - but then the user change it manually from the system UI you will not longer be able to change the brightness from code (until app restart) - Apple may have some logic that prevent too frequent/unwanted changes.

This is only my observation - there is no such information in the documentation

Comment: I noticed the same too. I am developing an app where I need to force the brightness to stay at 100. Have you found a way to keep it at a certain brightness? What I do currently, is force the brightness to 100, then if the user adjusts the brightness again, there'll be an alert where they can't proceed with the task until the brightness is max.

Comment: EDIT: I just found out just now that if you set it just a bit different it will work. I.e writing two lines consecutively like 
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(1.0)
        UIScreen.main.brightness = CGFloat(0.99)

Comment: haha :) I think you need to ask the user to change it manually (as a fail-safe only) - Apple obviously want the user to be in control. Even if it works for you it may not work on all devices

Comment: @sickerin very grateful for your tip about the double change, seems to work like a charm